# Python TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
# capture the number of players
def people():
    users = (input("how many players? "))
    while users.isdigit() == False:
        users = (input("how many players? "))
    users = int(users)

# capture each player's name
def player_name():
    for person in range(people):
        name = input("player's name?  ")
        players[name] = []
    
game_type = input("ongoing competition or single play?  ")
players = {}

if game_type == 'single play':
    people()

    player_name() # <<< error
```

When the code gets to `player_name()` at the bottom I get this error.

> TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you want `people` in `player_name()` to represent?

Comment: @quamrana In `player_name()`  `people` used to be `users` but I got an error saying 'users' is not defined.  After I input the number of players, I want to name each player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to pass various parameters around?

```py
# capture the number of players
def people():
    users = input("how many players? ")
    while not users.isdigit():
        users = input("how many players? ")
    return int(users)

# capture each player's name
def player_name(num_users, players):
    for person in range(num_users):
        name = input("player's name?  ")
        players[name] = []

    
game_type = input("ongoing competition or single play?  ")
players = {}

if game_type == 'single play':
    player_name(people(), players)
```

What happens in the line: `player_name(people(), players)` is that first `people()` is called which asks the user for the number of players and that number is returned and used as the first parameter to `player_name()`.

The second parameter is just the `dict` `players` which you created. This allows the possibility of moving `def player_name()` into another module which might not already know about `players`.

Then `player_name()` is called and asks for player's names as you have written.

Comment: can you explain how this works  `if game_type == 'single play':
    player_name(people(), players)`

Answer (score 2):

In the people() function, add a return statement returning the users variable.

Then, pass it as a parameter to the player_name() function :

```
# capture the number of players
def people():
    users = (input("how many players? "))
    while users.isdigit() == False:
        users = (input("how many players? "))
    users = int(users)
    return users

# capture each player's name
def player_name(people, players):
    for person in range(people):
        name = input("player's name?  ")
        players[name] = []
    
game_type = input("ongoing competition or single play?  ")
players = {}

if game_type == 'single play':
    num_people = people()

    player_name(num_people, players)
```